# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error when loading RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on rails. when loading localhost:3000/demo/index , ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error appears. I have checked datbase.yml and it seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Gemfile and check you have sqlite3 gem there.

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

after performing 'bundle install' ensure you execute following commands to create & migrate your Database.

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Hope that helps.